# Deepsecurity's Management Console

Tags: deepsecurity

asked DSM and solved Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trend Micro Deep Security Manager runs on port 4119 by default, which is unlikely to be in-use by other products.  Please see https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/12_0/on-premise/Manage-Components/ports.html for more details.

I am a Trend Micro employee.

Thanks,
Nick